# No such host is known в Dns.GetHostEntry

Tags: c#, .net, windows, clr

При вызове `Dns.GetHostEntry` (или `Dns.GetHostEntryAsync`) валится ошибка:

> No such host is known
>   at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostEntry(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Наблюдается это на разных осях. Замечено это было на `.NET 4.7.2`.

Вызвана эта ошибка Именем компьютера, состоящим только из цифр. Например имя компьютера: `3410890` вызывает данную ошибку. Если имя компьютера выглядит так: `WIN-1234567` то ошибки не наблюдается.

Чем вызвана эта ошибка, где она возникает и как программно ее исправить?

Comment: Точно дело в имени компьютера? Вы пробовали проблемный компьютер переименовывать в другое имя и у вас все успешно прошло?

Comment: Ни полное доменное имя в DNS, ни имя компьютера в NetBIOS (начиная c Windows 2000) не могут состоять только из цифр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что внутри [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/Net/DNS.cs,78e8698bef96d9f6) вызывается [`IPAddress.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2). И он успешно парсит строку `3410890`, как IP и => вся последующая работа этого метода неверная, так как пытается достучаться по несуществующему IP.

В MSDN написано, что это баг, но его правка нарушит работу существующих приложений:

> Note that this method accepts as valid an ipString value that can be
>   parsed as an Int64, and then treats that Int64 as the long value of an
>   IP address in network byte order, similar to the way that the
>   IPAddress constructor does. This means that this method returns true
>   if the Int64 is parsed successfully, even if it represents an address
>   that's not a valid IP address. For example, if ipString is "1", this
>   method returns true even though "1" (or 0.0.0.1) is not a valid IP
>   address and you might expect this method to return false. Fixing this
>   bug would break existing apps, so the current behavior will not be
>   changed. Your code can avoid this behavior by ensuring that it only
>   uses this method to parse IP addresses in dotted-decimal format.

Возможно в .NET CORE его пофиксили, так как перед ними не ставилась задача обратной совместимости.

Что бы этого не было используйте другую перегрузку и в ручную передавайте созданный вами собственноручно объект`IPAddress`.